# Linux Desktop Access via Web Browser

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, file-sharing, browser, remote-desktop

This should be pretty simple, in my naive opinion of course...

I have a tower that I am going to run a media server off of, along with some other functions but that's the main (re)purpose of the parts I had around.

I'd like to be able to access the Debian (or other Linux) desktop environment via a web browser, like you can do for a printer or wireless router etc.  The goal being that from any device on my wireless network I can just type in the ip and login as if I were in front of the box itself. This way I can download stuff, manage sharedrives, etc from any network device but all the actions happen on my media server.

Is there anything out there like this besides this VNC thing I've read about?

Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Don't think so. Java is the enabler here. You could run an RDP server on Linux as an alternative.

Comment: If you're simply after web console acces, google Ajaxterm, it'll be in Debian Etch.

Comment: You don't need the desktop to do any of those things. Why don't you just ssh into it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome and Chrome Remote Desktop are excellent userland options, as @jcbermu has already suggested. Other options would include something like VNC, which can seem a bit daunting at first but is actually not too hard.

If you want to minimize what needs to be installed on the computer you are using to access the media server, you could use guacamole (http://guacamole.apache.org/) to make the VNC server available to any computer on the network with an html5 compliant web-browser.

Another option is the commercial software Teamviewer (free for personal use) http://www.teamviewer.com

Answer (score 0):

1 - Install Google Chrome and [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) on the media server.

2-  On other PCs, from Google Chrome you will be able to acccess the graphical interface of the media server.

Answer (score 0):

I could accomplish this with Guacamole and blogged about it: http://linuxintro.org/wiki/Guacamole

Basically Guacamole uses Tomcat to export a VNC desktop to web.